# Compiler Issue with Generics and Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have 2 classes with the following declarations:

> - `abstract class ClassBase<T, S> where T : myType where S : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`
> - `abstract class ServiceBase<T> where T : myType`

and I have 2 other classes, that inherit one from each, we can call *ClassInherited* and *ServiceInherited*. Note that the two Service classes are not in the same project as the other two.

The idea is that in the `ServiceBase` class I can declare a property like `protected ClassBase<T,System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject> Class { get; set; }` and then in the inherited service`s constructor something like `this.Class = ClassInheritedInstance`

I already implemented the idea but it gives me this error when assigning the *Class* property in the ServiceInherited class constructor:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClassInherited' to 'ClassBase< T, S>'

Note that ClassInherited is indeed an specification of `Class<T,S>`... it's just that the compiler doesn't seem to be able to tell the types correctly. Also changing the declaration of the class property to `protected ClassBase<T, EntityObjectInherited>` works, and *EntityObjectInherited* is an implementation of `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`... I don't see why is there a problem.

### Update 1

Note that at compile time the type of `ClassInherited` is known, as its declaration is `public class ClassInherited : ClassBase<myTypeInherited, EntityObjectInherited>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### INITIAL ANSWER

The reason that you cannot use `protected ClassBase<T,S> Class { get; set; }` in the ServiceInherited-class is that you do not know the S-type that is needed to declare a type of the property Class.

You have to options:

- Include the S type in the specification of the Service-type: `abstract class ServiceBase<T, S> where T : myType where S : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`
- Implement an interface for ClassBase with only the T-type, so that you can refer to a class-inherited-object without using the S-type. Then you CAN have a property in the service class (of the interface-type), since you do not need to specify the S-type.

Note that generic-type-checking is not checked at run-time, but at compile-time. Else it wouldn't be strong-typing.

### UPDATE

The reason the cast won't work is that type `ClassBase<T, EntityObjectInherited>` is not equal or castable to `ClassBase<T, System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject>`. Covariance doesn't work on class-types, only on interface-types.

I think the solution here is to work with interfaces. Use an interface for class-base, say `IClassBase<T>`. That way you can omit the S-type in the signature of the class, and only have it in the interface.

### UPDATE (2)

One thing you can do is to create an interface for the Class property. You can define the following interface.

```
public interface IClass<T> where T : myType {
    // TODO
    // Define some interface definition, but you cannot use the
    // EntityObject derived class, since they are not to be known 
    // in the service class.      
}
```

If you implement this interface on your ClassBase class, and add a constructor on your ServiceBase class which accepts an object of type IClass, then you can push this object to property Class in the base-class. Like this:

```
public abstract class ClassBase<T, S> : IClass<T>
    where T : MyType
    where S : EntityObject {
}

public abstract class ServiceBase<T> where T : MyType {
    protected ServiceBase(IClass<T> classObject) {
        Class = classObject;
    }
    protected IClass<T> Class { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceInherited : ServiceBase<MyTypeDerived> {
    public ServiceInherited(IClass<MyTypeDerived> classObject)
        : base(classObject) {
    }
}
```

One thing to note, is not to expose the S-type of the ClassBase to the interface. Since you do not want the Service-classes to know this type, they cannot actively call any methods or use properties that somehow have the S-type in their definition.

Comment: The property in the ServiceBase is declared as: `protected ClassBase<T, System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject> Class { get; set; }` shouldn't S type be known by then?... The reason I don't want to include *S* in the declaration of ServiceBase is because *S* is an object that should only exist in the DAL, and the services project should only work with the classes exposed by DAL, remember that S, in this case, is a data entity object.

Comment: Can you elaborate a small example of how would ClassBase, IClassBase and ServiceBase be used? Management agreed we may change the ClassBase project and I've been trying to get it working but still I have the same error...

Comment: I had a small issue at the end for which I couldn't implement your solution but it definitely answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This ugly boxing, unboxing should work :

```
Class = (ClassBase<T, S>)(object)new ClassInherited();
```

---

Covariance is allowed only with generic interface today ?[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

This works :

```
// Covariance. 
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
// An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument  
// is assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument.  
// Assignment compatibility is preserved. 
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

This doesn't :

```
 List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        List<object> objects = strings;
```

Comment: It did work on compile time, still need to test it on run time. Can you explain why does it work? Also, don't boxing and unboxing happen only for when casting value types into `object`?

Comment: You're totally right for boxing/unboxing ! The compiler can't reject this, cause you can cast anything to an object and you can can cast an object to anything ... but InvalidCastException might occur on runtime when the cast is invalid !

Answer (score 0):

The compiler won't be able to guess that *ClassInherited* is indeed a correct match for *ClassBase<T, S>* as it does not know the exact types of *T* and *S*, that will be decided at generics type instanciation at runtime.

So if you're sure that at runtime the types will be compatible you can safely try a cast :

```
Class = ClassInheritedInstance as ClassBase<T, S>
```

This will only have a slight (not to say negligible) overhead as the CLR will need to check the compatibility of the types to have *safe* code.

Comment: Added `Update 1` to question.

Comment: If PedroC88 is sure that `ClassInheritedInstance` _is_ a `ClassBase<T, S>` (which it sounds to be the case), then I'd recommend using an explicit cast conversion: `Class = (ClassBase<T, S>)ClassInheritedInstance` instead of an `as`. `as` will return `null` on a bad cast which can have other effects (such as `NullReferenceException`) later when the real issue is that he has a non-convertable type due to a bug in the first place.

Comment: I did try the explicit cast before, and now tried this one. None compile and give similar errors.

Comment: @Serious Your statement 'that will be decided at generics type instanciation at runtime' is incorrect. Generics are matched/checked/... at compile-time. Not at run-time.